# App specific logging and export in Android

Tags: android, android-logcat

My app logs debug information and phone state using logcat at present. What I need is the following:

- Is there a way to send all my logs to my app's private (say encrypted) storage not accessible to others in a neat fashion?
- I would also like to clean up and export these logs, say once every 24 hrs to my TCP server

What would be the quickest and the cleanest way to go about doing this? I understand that I could write my custom logging service that does this and use something like an AlarmManager to export the logs, but I was wondering if there exist automated solutions since the task itself appears to be quite ubiquitous.

The idea behind all this is to monitor the performance of my app, possible bugs which would enable me to work on updates. Something like automated crowd sourced feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Analytics which "provides a web service and a pair of SDKs to help track user interaction with websites and applications accessed from a mobile device"

Link: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

Also, actual errors that cause your app to force close will show up in your android developer account, with the same detail as in logcat.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it would be nicer to have it submit to my personal TCP server though. I have my own database residing in the cloud and intend to do post processing with it. Perhaps a class that aggregates logs and writes it to a stream of my choice, in this case, a socketstream at specified intervals.

Comment: @Rajikistan: Maybe it is nicer to work with the Analytics API than to implement it all on your own. I found this post about extracting data from Analytics and working with it: http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/05/merging-google-analytics-with-your-data-warehouse/